# Why did Captain Charlotte raise her hand for Yuno?

Tags: black-clover

So we know that Blue Rose Knights only works with ladies and not any men.

So why Captain Charlotte raised hand for Yuno during selection for magic knights?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding something--men *can* join the Blue Rose Knights. It's just very uncommon.

From the *Black Clover wiki:*

> The squad is mostly women, having the sharp motto of refusing the notion of worshiping or idealizing men. ... **The few male squad members** serve as errand boys. <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

I think that's where the mistake is. Men can indeed join the Blue Rose Knights, but the squad is primarily based and filled with women, and the men are just used as servants/errand boys. Explained above in the wiki, they do not like the idea of praising men. This does not mean they can't join the Blue Rose Knights. There's a few male members that just serve as errand boys for the women in the group.

So, Captain Charlotte raised her hand for Yuno because men *can* indeed join the Blue Rose Knights. It's just very uncommon, and that's why explained in the wiki quote that ***few*** men are in it, but they're just errand boys.

---

(Someone asked a similar question on the fandom, you can check [***here***](https://blackclover.fandom.com/f/p/3238260495089945546) for more info.)

Comment: But wouldn't it be the waste of potential ,I mean she would only use him as errand boy and his potential would be wasted. This is also unexpected that she only raised her hand for a 4 leaf grimoire holder just so that he can work instead of fighting.

Comment: It would indeed. But, they don't like praising men so they just make them servants, if you will. It's pretty stupid when they're much more capable than that. But we can't fault that logic since they generally *don't like* men lol